# Supplying array type argument to Argparse from an environment variable

Tags: linux, zsh, argparse

Using this piece of code to collect command line args, I would like to provide the argument using an ENV variable but the substitution does not happen in the intended way.

```py
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-m", default=[], nargs="+")
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
```

```
$ python test.py -m a1 a2
```

Output:

> Namespace(m=['a1', 'a2'])

```
$ ARGS="a1 a2"; python test.py -m $ARGS
```

Output:

> Namespace(m=['a1 b1'])

So, the question is, how can I provide -m using an ENV variable, so that argparse recognizes it as an array and not as a single arg? Thanks! (I'm using zsh here)

Comment: In cases like this it's a good idea to look at `sys.argv`, to see what the parser has to work with.  If that list is `['test.py', '-m', 'a1 b1']`, the parser is giving you exactly what `zsh` provided.

Comment: Technically speaking, you can't, since you environment variables and arguments hold strings, not arrays. Of yourse you can pass a string and then convert the string to a Python array, which you can then process further.

Comment: Try the `=` expansion: `ARGS="a1 a2"; python test.py -m ${=ARGS}`.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because zsh does not split variables by default, but you can set the [`SH_WORD_SPLIT`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/FAQ/zshfaq03.html) variable to have it behave like e.g., bash.

```
SH_WORD_SPLIT=1 M="1 2 3" python3 mcve.py -m $M
Namespace(m=['1', '2', '3'])
```

If you don't want to do this, you can always manually split the arguments passed, but that kind of defeats the purpose of the `ArgumentParser` in the first place.

Comment: Doesn't work for me:
$ SH_WORD_SPLIT=1; M="1 2 3"; python3 test_args.py -m $M

Namespace(m=['1 2 3'])

Comment: I think you wanted `setopt SH_WORD_SPLIT` or `setopt shwordsplit` to change `zsh` to behave like `bash`. To affect just a single instance, you can use the `=` expansion : `${=M}`.